# How to center the FFT of sine wave in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot the FFT of a sine wave using matplotlib and I want to plot a single line at a frequency where the sine wave belongs.

here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


f = 3
t = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.01)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)


plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, y)


ft = np.fft.fft(y)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(ft.real)

plt.show()
```

And, here's the output of the above code.

[image: FFT]

I want to plot the FFT as a single line, and this single line will be straight up at the given sine wave's frequency. Suppose, if I have two sine waves of 20Hz and 40Hz added together like `sine(2*pi*20*t) + sine(2*pi*40*t)` then their FFT should have two straight lines at 20Hz and 30Hz.

How do I fix my code to get what I wanted? I've seen many questions here on StackOverflow but I did not understand them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i guess you need to use fftfreq. check the examples here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to unpack here.

#### Use `np.fft.rfft` for real signals

Since your signal is real-valued (i.e. no complex numbers) there is no information contained in the second half of your fft. You should use the `rfft` in stead for real signals.

See [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#real-and-hermitian-transforms) section of the numpy docs.

#### Use `abs` to get the amplitude

You seem to be interested in the amplitude of each frequency component. The amplitude is obtained by taking the absolute value of the fft:

```py
ft = np.fft.rfft(y)
amplitude = abs(ft)
```

See [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#implementation-details) section of the numpy docs for more information.

#### Correctly scale the frequencies

You can use `np.fft.rfftfreq` to get the frequencies of each component, however these will be scaled by `1 / number of points`.

To scale the frequencies so that they match your `f` parameter you will need to know the time delta between the points in your series:

```py
delta_t = 0.01
t = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, delta_t)
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(t)) / delta_t
```

#### Putting it all together

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Extract delta_t to rescale the frequencies later
delta_t = 0.01
t = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, delta_t)

# Signal is a mixture of 2 frequencies
f0 = 3
f1 = 8
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t) + 0.5 * np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, y)

ft = np.fft.rfft(y)

# Frequency of each component, scaled like f0 and f1
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(t)) / delta_t

# Amplitude of each frequency is given by the absolute value
amplitude = abs(ft)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(freq, amplitude)
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')

plt.show()
```

[image: The result]

Comment: exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot for this!